# Node Express routes - Absolute URL vs Relative URL

Tags: node.js, express, routes, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a simple form of this type

```
<form name="keywords" action="www.mydomain.com:6161/articles" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keyword" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The Express 4 routes for handling the form post, is as follows

```
app.post('/articles', routes.article.keyword);
```

The actual route file has the following

```
exports.keyword = function(req,res,next){
    res.send(req.body.keyword);
};
```

Based on the above circumstances, when I post the form in the browser, I see a page “The address wasn’t understood”.

But, if I use relative URL in the form action i.e.,

It works perfect. Why so?

Because in reality, I sometimes may have to post data to a different domain or URL altogether.

Comment: You need to specify either a full url `http://..../action` or a relative one. If you're posting to the same host, there's no need to specify full url

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will post my comment as an answer as it helped.

In order for the action to work, you need to either specify full url, that include schema:

```
<form name="keywords" action="http://www.example.com/articles" method="post">
```

Or you can just use a relative url:

```
<form name="keywords" action="/articles" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

a relative *path* is one not starting with a / (forward-slash)... generally, this will attempt to load from the current url's base dir (you can set this in html, though the browsers default to the 'dirname' of the url (e.g. 'img/something.gif' on a page at '/some/path/index.html' will fetch it from /some/path/img/something.gif').

an absolute path is one starting with a /.  it will be loaded using the same schema, host and optionally, port,user, etc (full url syntax: scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]... read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

a full url is one starting with a schema (http/https/ftp,etc...)... however (this comes in handy): if you're going to be using the same schema (which keeps your site's security score high), you can skip it, along with the colon.

e.g.:  while viewing a site from 'https://blah.net', and attempting to load a resource from google (analytics maybe), you can reference it as:

'//google.com/path/to/whatever'

this will use https if the page was loaded over https, or http if not... keeps you from having to determine the scheme that was used when rendering the page.

Comment: Please note that `//` will only work in a server (even localhost), but not if you just open a local `.html` file with the browser